# SelectMany Count generates explicit sql statement

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework

I have a structure like that:

```
public class Tag
{
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Vacancy> Vacancies { get; set; }
        // ...
}

public class Vacancy
{
        public int VacancyId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        // ...
}
```

These entities are mapped to MS SQL with EF / Code First approach.

After that I fetch somehow from the context (based on user query) a list of tags:

```
List<Tag> userSelectedTags = ...;
```

I want to calculate how much vacancies these tags contain:

```
int count = userSelectedTags.SelectMany(t => t.Vacancies).Count();
```

It works fine, but it seems this query is not well optimized. When I run into profiler, I get this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent2].[VacancyId] AS [VacancyId], 
[Extent2].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent2].[Salary] AS [Salary], 

...props... etc...

FROM  [dbo].[VacancyTagVacancies] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Vacancies] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Vacancy_VacancyId] = [Extent2].[VacancyId]
WHERE [Extent1].[VacancyTag_VacancyTagId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=1
```

In other words, it doesn't use COUNT sql keyword, but just returns the whole collection and calculates it outside SQL Server.

How can I optimize the LINQ query in order to use COUNT here instead of selecting all? Thanks.

Comment: Does `userSelectedTags.Select(t => t.Vacancies.Count()).Sum()` come out any better?

Comment: Nope, the query is same. I think it is not because of SelectMany, it looks like it depends on t.Vacancies

Answer (score 1):

Your `userSelectedTags` isn't a query, which means `t.Vacancies` becomes a reference to the client-side property, which when enumerated retrieves all the `Vacancies` for that specific `Tag`. The `Count` then runs on the client side.

You need to start from the server side:

```
int count = (
    from tag in context.Tags
    where userSelectedTags.Contains(tag)
    from v in tag.Vacancies
    select v).Count();
```

You *might* need to make a `userSelectedTagIds` instead of `userSelectedTags` if this doesn't yet work.

Comment: it gives compilation error: The range variable 'tag' conflicts with a previous declaration of 'tag'

Comment: @user337085 If you already have a variable `tag` in scope, you need to rename the one here. `from t in context.Tags where userSelectedTags.Contains(t) from v in t.Vacancies select v`

Comment: it doesn't work with userSelectedTags, but works fine with userSelectedTagIds. Thanks, man! You're genius!

Comment: ah, and one more issue is that works fine only if userSelectedTagIds contains 1 tag id. But if there are two of them, linq translates the query into something like "AND ([Extent1].[Tag_TagId] IN (1,8))" and it returns malformed OR-result. But I need here AND-result.

Comment: @user337085 That matches the results of what you had in your question. I'm not seeing what result you're asking for, could you edit your question to give an expression that gives you the right results?

Comment: @user337085 I *think* you mean the number of vacancies that are in all of the user's selected tags? If so, it's somewhat more complicated and I'll attempt to answer it when I have spare time.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to execute the SQL directly like this:

```
string nativeSQLQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM <tables join>";

var queryResult = ctx.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(nativeSQLQuery);
```